# Converting jni code to renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

I want to convert my existing jni code into renderscript because I think there will be a performance benefit. I have no idea about renderscript but I want to ask this:

My jni code uses sha computation taken from openSSL libs. Is there any way to compute sha on renderscript directly? Or Will I have to convert openSSL libs into renderscript code as well? That sounds like a hard job since I have no idea how to do it. Any other ideas on how to compute Sha on renderscript?

Comment: How many SHA computations do you need to do?

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk probably 3-4 computations of Sha-1

Comment: Related: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/733/accelerating-sha-1

Answer (score 1):

You will have to port an existing SHA-1 algorithm of your choice to [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) (C99-like), add few modifications to benefits of the [parallelism](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#writing-an-rs-kernel) and take in account few subtleties related to Renderscript itself (no malloc, static versus non static, etc).

You might also search on github or other public code source repository if someone has already implemented it, for example AES has been.